# Django allauth social signup with custom user-model + form

Tags: python, django, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, django-allauth

I'm trying to use django-allauth package to handle my social login/signup with google oauth2 authentication.
What I'm trying to do is after the google authentication pass the new user to a custom signup form with some custom fields to my user model and only after that to save the user model.
Everything I try just ignore my custom form and save the user without passing my form.

It would be awesome if you can list the necessary elements in the project to make this thing work.

Thanks in advance,
Itai

Comment: Did you add `ACCOUNT_FORMS = {'signup': 'your.forms.SignupForm'}` in settings?

Comment: yes, of course.